# How to retrieve the previous list object when looping over a list in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Assume that I have a list

```
mylist <- list(5, 7, 9, 16)
```

And I want to make a function that calculates the difference in between a list object and the object before (i.e., in this case 7-5=2, 9-7=2, 16-9=7)

```
myfunction <- function(myvalue, myvalue_minus1){
  myvalue - myvalue_minus1
}

# Example
myresult <- myfunction(7, 5)
> myresult 
[1] 2
```

I want to count the difference in between all list objects, so I loop the function over the list.

However, how do I express that I want `myvalue_minus1` always to be the previous value of the list (i.e., when `value_i == [[2]]`, how do I get the loop to retrieve `myvalue_minus1 == [[1]]` ?

```
myvalue_list <- list()
for(value_i in 1:4){
  myvalue_list[[value_i]] <- myfunction(myvalue = value_i, myvalue_minus1)
}

# Desired output
> myvalue_list
[[1]]
[1] 5      # not sure if the first value should be 0 or 5

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 7
```

I've tried something like

```
myvalue_list <- list()
for(value_i in 1:4){
  myvalue_list[[value_i]] <- myfunction(myvalue = value_i, myvalue_minus1 = value_i[[i]] -1 ) # wrong
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The `myfunction` function is just to make an easily reproducible example, the function that I'm working with does something else. Thus, I'm only interested in answers that solve the question stated in the title.

**EDIT 2**
Added the desired output

Comment: Would you print the output you want from the function ?

Comment: Try `value_i[[i - 1]] ` instead of `value_i[[i]] -1`

Comment: Thanks Dohamed Desouky. Trying your suggestion gives the error message `Error in value_i[[i - 1]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: Thats because you begin from `i = 1` means `value_i[[0]]` which out of bounds try begin from `2:4` and `myvalue_list[[value_i-1]]`

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error message. Did seem very reasonable though!

Comment: Try the function in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```r
myvalue_list <- list()
for(value_i in 2:4){
    myvalue_list[[value_i-1]] <- myfunction(myvalue = mylist[[value_i]],
    myvalue_minus1 = mylist[[value_i-1]])
}

myvalue_list

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 7
```

Comment: Yes of course, I had missed the `mylist` in the loop as well. This did the trick. Thank you so much for taking the time!